# XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working on a web interface to configure and monitoring our device. In order to monitoring I'm using XMLHttpRequest object created when the user is successfully connected and closed at the end of the web session. Our device's software reports information about device's status via the created asynch channel.
On Firefox (67.0.2) the callback is never called instead on an old version (33.1) works.
Any idea for this behavior 
Thanks

```
function openAsynchChannel(){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // Native support of XMLHttpRequest
    Communication_asynchChannel = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    Communication_asynchChannel = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

Communication_asynchChannel.open("POST", "update.html", true);
Communication_asynchChannel.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Communication_asynchChannel.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html");

Communication_asynchChannel.timeout = 0;

Communication_asynchChannel.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
Communication_asynchChannel.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

Communication_asynchChannel.send("CMD_TYPE=1|&PARAMETER1=" + navigator.appCodeName + "_" + (new Date()).getMinutes() + "\r\n");        

// Hook the callback
Communication_asynchChannel.onreadystatechange = Communication_receiveAsync;

}

function Communication_receiveAsync(){
    console.log(Communication_asynchChannel.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Try to set it before sending the request. First `onreadystatechange = ...` then `send(...)`

Comment: Thanks Florent, but same result.

Comment: Weird, I tryed your code (with a different request ip) on FF 68 and it works.
Are you sure `update.html` is on the same server than your client, don't you have any `Cross-Origin Request` error ? And stupid question, but just in case, are you sure to call the `openAsynchChannel()` function at any time ?